# runAs for Alfresco CMIS queries?

Tags: alfresco, opencmis

We integrated Alfresco in our enterprise integration platform using CMIS.
Now we are wondering if there is an official or unofficial way to run queries against the alfresco cmis api using runAs similar to a REMOTE_USER for SSO login sending the username for the permission downgrade in the request header/body since the integration platform has no end user credentials and should not handle alfresco tickets on a per user basis.

The only way I found so far was Jeff's suggestion made in [Alfresco Community OAuth2 SSO via CMIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52859717/alfresco-community-oauth2-sso-via-cmis) to configure Alfresco for external auth but then we have to handle per user sessions from the integration platform to Alfresco instead of using one session sending the user in the request which we use in other custom java code.